# Javascript - is there a better way to check an string instead of indexOf

Tags: javascript

I use this code and My question would be if there is a better way to check a string than **indexOf**:

```
if(documentFile.ending.indexOf('pdf') > -1 || documentFile.ending.indexOf('PDF') > -1 || documentFile.ending.indexOf('docx') > -1)
```

Comment: Yeah you have it in ES6. Or you can use regex to do this
if (/pdf/i.test(documentFile.ending))

Comment: I was thinking regex as well: /pdf/.test(documentFile.ending)

Comment: Please define "better". Better in what? What is wrong with `indexOf` ?

Answer (score 2):

ES6 has boolean function. Use:

```
if ( documentFile.ending.includes('pdf') ) { }
```

Or for regex:

```
if ( documentFile.ending.match(/your-regex/) { }
```

Example spec: https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ES6 then you may want to look at [***String.prototype.includes***](https://developer.mozilla.org/uk/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes)

```
var str = 'To be, or not to be, that is the question.';
console.log(str.includes('To be'));       // true
```

Comment: @Orangesandlemons no it doesnt. have you seen the polyfill for `String.prototype.includes` ?

Comment: sorry, got mixed up with string.includes/indexOf and array.includes/indexOf. Removed original comment

Answer (score 0):

In ES6 you have better option to use "includes"

otherwise use regex

```
if(/pdf/i.test(documentFile.ending))
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, `indexOf` is really fast, a lot faster than using a regular expression. But something like `/pdf$/i.test(str)` lets you test the end as well as giving you case-insensitivity. But you could be more precise:

```
function endsWith(str, ending) {
    return str != null
        && ending != null
        && ending.length <= str.length
        && str.lastIndexOf(ending) === str.length - ending.length;
}
```

Note the `ending.length <= str.length` which is there so that you don't do something like `endsWith("", "a")` and get `true`. :)